# Nginx - 301 moved permanently "problem"

Tags: nginx

As a Nginx noob, I have a problem which I can't solve. 
In Nginx website configuration I have:

```
server {
       listen 443;
       listen [::]:443;

       ssl on;
       ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.eu/fullchain.pem;
       ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.eu/privkey.pem;

       server_name website.eu www.website.eu;
       index index.html index.htm index.php;
       root /var/www/website;

       location / {
                  try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
       }

       location /pihole {
                        alias /var/www/html;
                        try_files $uri $uri/ /admin/index.php?$query_string;
       }

       location ~ \.php$ {
                         include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                         fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
       }
}
```

Website works, but the Pihole was installed in `/var/www/html` folder.
If I try to access it, I get:

```
  user@website:~$ curl -i https://www.website.eu/pihole
    HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
    Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
    Date: Fri, 01 Nov 2019 11:29:13 GMT
    Content-Type: text/html
    Content-Length: 194
    Location: https://www.website.eu/pihole/
    Connection: keep-alive
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's check:

- your current configuration `try_files` directive:

  ```
  try_files $uri $uri/ /admin/index.php?$query_string;
  ```
- `index` directive:

  ```
  index index.html index.htm index.php;
  ```
- your requested URL path is `/pihole`, which matches `location /pihole`, which in turn is aliased:

  ```
  alias /var/www/html
  ```

Okay, so when you request for `/pihole` (`$uri`), `nginx` will sequentially do:

- check for `$uri` first, but it can't match that as `/pihole` is alised to a location so no file can't be matched
- move onto `$uri/` next (this causes the 301 redirection); so after resolving the `alias` the final filesystem path becomes `/var/www/website/` and then tries to see if there is any file referred by `index` in this directory, so tries `index.html`, `index.htm`, `index.php` sequentially here -- the first one found wins and a response is sent.
- If the second step fails, it moves onto the last one i.e. `/admin/index.php?$query_string` -- this is an absolute path so it is matched from the server `root`. Hence the final path becomes: `/var/www/website/admin/index.php?$query_string` as the `root` is set as `/var/www/website`. If a file `/var/www/website/admin/index.php` is found, it is passed the `query_string` and the resulting response is sent.
- If nothing matches, a 404 is sent eventually.

Like I mentioned earlier, in your case, the second (`$uri/`) is causing the 301 redirection that you're seeing. While we're at this, in case of redirection, always check out the `Location` directive to find out the redirected URL:

```
Location: https://www.website.eu/pihole/
```

---

Now, a good practice while using `location` is to use trailing `/` unless you're do a generic/unbound match. So for example, `location /pihole` matches `/pihole`, `/piholefoo`, `/piholebar` and so on. But you don't probably want that. So you should be precise in this case:

```
location /pihole/ {
    # Note trailing / here as well
    alias /var/www/html/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /admin/index.php?$query_string;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your explanation. At the same time as you wrote this, I moved the "root /var/www/website;" inside the first Location block (for /). And it starts responding. Now I have another problem, but it is probably not in connection with Nginx settings.

Comment: @JanezKranjski ummmm...I don't think I told you to move `root`. I've mentioned all the basic stuffs you need to know. If you're stuck at some place, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: you are right. Now I tried from the scratch (from suggestions from Pihole site) and it works now. I will probably have new questions when I will start changing folder and URL structure :-) but it will be new question :-) Thank you.

Comment: @JanezKranjski No problem :)